# Formatting of multicolumn table

Tags: tables

I have created the following table:

```
 \begin{landscape}

\begin{table}
    \footnotesize
    \caption{Faktorladungsstruktur und Kommunalitäten der EFA mit ML-Extraktion und Varimax-Rotation}   
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3.5pt}
    %{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
    %\scalebox{0.65}{%
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X*{8}{S[table-format=2.2]}} 

        \toprule
        & \multicolumn{7}{c}{Faktorladungen} & {Kommunalität} \\ \cmidrule(r){2-8} \cmidrule(l){9-9}
        Items & {1} & {2} & {3} & {4} & {5} & {6} &{7}&{$h^2$}\\ \midrule
        17. I will keep up with fashions in hair and clothing & 0.84  &  & &  &&  & & 0.73  \\
        11. I will have people comment often about how attractive I look. &  0.81  &  & &  &&  & &  0.72 \\
        23. I will achieve the \enquote{look} I've been after.&  0.72  &  & &  &&  & & 0.59 \\
        18. I will have many expensive possessions.&  0.71  &  & &  &&  & & 0.62 \\
        29. My image will be one others find appealing.&  0.65  &  & &  &&  & & 0.50 \\ 
        05. I will successfully hide the signs of aging.& 0.47 & &  & &  &&  & 0.36  \\
        30. I will have enough money to buy everything I want. &  0.44  &&& 0.45 &&&& 0.47 \\
        15. I will work to make the world a better place.        & & 0.80 &&&&&& 0.68 \\
        09. I will work for the betterment of society.  &  & 0.75 &&&&&& 0.59 \\

        27. I will help people in need.     & & 0.74 &&&&&& 0.63 \\
        21. I will help others improve their lives.     &  & 0.73 &&&&&& 0.63 \\
        03. I will assist people who need it, asking nothing in return.     &  & 0.52 &&&&&& 0.34 \\
        25. I will continue to grow and learn new things.& &&&&&&& 0.34 \\      
        14. I will share my life with someone I love.   &  && 0.73 &&&&& 0.60 \\    
        20. I will have committed, intimate relationships.  &  && 0.73 &&&&& 0.57 \\    
        26. I will have deep, enduring relationships.       & &&  0.71 &&&&& 0.58 \\
        02. I will feel that there are people who really love me, and whom I love.      &  && 0.54 &&&&& 0.37 \\
        07. At the end of my life, I will look back on my life as meaningful and complete.      &  &&&&&&& 0.36 \\
        08. I will have good friends that I can count on.& &&&&&&& 0.27 \\      
        12. I will have a job that pays very well.&  &&& 0.88 &&&& 0.86 \\      
        06. I will be financially successful.   &  &&& 0.80 &&&& 0.80 \\    
        24. I will be rich.     &  0.44  &&& 0.51 &&&& 0.57 \\
        10. My name will be known by many people.   &  0.40  &&&& 0.71 &&& 0.79 \\  
        04. I will be recognized by lots of different people.   & &&&& 0.70 &&& 0.64 \\ 
        16. I will be admired by many people.   &  0.43  &&&& 0.60 &&& 0.63 \\  
        19. I will know and accept who I really am.     &  &&&&& 0.67 && 0.55 \\
        13. I will gain increasing insight into why I do the things I do.   &  &&&&& 0.48 && 0.36 \\    
        01. I will choose what I do, instead of being pushed along by life. &  &&&&&&& 0.19 \\  
        22. I will be famous.       &  0.46  &&&&&& 0.72 & 0.82 \\
        28. My name will appear frequently in the media.    &  0.42  &&&&&& 0.71 & 0.74 \\  
        \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
        Varianzaufklärung in \% & 14.71 & 10.50 & 8.13 & 7.52 & 5.89 & 4.91 & 4.52 &{Gesamt}\\
    \end{tabularx}

\end{table}
\end{landscape}
```

Right now it looks something like this: 
[image: Table after incorporating @leandriis suggestions]
Do you guys have any suggestions on how to center the word "Faktorladungen" across the columns, where it says 1 2 3 etc. Also, how can I center h² under the word "Kommunalitäten".

Btw, where would you put the word "items"? Do you think it is okay, where it is or would you place it somewhere else?

I am using the \documentclass[paper=a4, pagesize, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl}.

I hope that you can help me with my issue here. Thanks a lot already in advanca.

Kind regards, 
Helena

Comment: Regarding "Faktorladungen": Currently you center the word with respect to the first 8 columns instead of centering if over column 2 to 8. Therefore use `& \multicolumn{7}{c}{Faktorladungen}` instead of `\multicolumn{8}{c}{Faktorladungen}`

Comment: Unrelated to the issue but I would recomment to not use `scalebox` on a table since this will result in inconsistent font sized.

Comment: Since all the items in the last column have the same width, it's easiest to just declare it as a "c" column.

Answer (score 4):

Here is my suggestion. In comparison to the original code, I made the following changes:

- replaced `\multicolumn{8}...` with `& \multicolumn{7}...` to correct
  the placement of "Faktorladungen"
- removed the scalebox since this will lead to inconsistent font sizes throughout the document
- removed the `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}` to save space
- changed the value of `\tabcolsep`to save some more space
- rotated the table to a landscape orientation since it will not fit onto a portrait page
- used `tabularx` to make the table as wide as the available space
- added `siunitx`'s `S`type columns to improve the alignment of the numbers
- removed all `$` around the numbers
- removed the `\newgeometry` since the table will fit into the page even without heavily decreasing the margin size
- decreased the font size to `\footnotesize` to make sure the table fits onto the page.

According to the suggestions from Mico in the comments, I have also added the following changes:

- removed the redundant `\multicolumn` around `Kommunalität` since non-numeric entries in a set of `{}` in an `S` type column are automatically horozontally centered
- replaced `\bottomrule` with `\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]` to improve the spacing
- removed the `\newline` in the last row

[image]

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, pagesize, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
\footnotesize
\caption{Faktorladungsstruktur und Kommunalitäten der EFA mit ML-Extraktion und Varimax-Rotation}   
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3.5pt}
%{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
%\scalebox{0.65}{%
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X*{8}{S[table-format=2.2]}} 

    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{7}{c}{Faktorladungen} & {Kommunalität} \\ \cmidrule(r){2-8} \cmidrule(l){9-9}
Items & {1} & {2} & {3} & {4} & {5} & {6} &{7}&{$h^2$}\\ \midrule
17. I will keep up with fashions in hair and clothing & 0.84  &  & &  &&  & & 0.73  \\
11. I will have people comment often about how attractive I look. &  0.81  &  & &  &&  & &  0.72 \\
23. I will achieve the \enquote{look} I've been after.&  0.72  &  & &  &&  & & 0.59 \\
18. I will have many expensive possessions.&  0.71  &  & &  &&  & & 0.62 \\
29. My image will be one others find appealing.&  0.65  &  & &  &&  & & 0.50 \\ 
05. I will successfully hide the signs of aging.& 0.47 & &  & &  &&  & 0.36  \\
30. I will have enough money to buy everything I want. &  0.44  &&& 0.45 &&&& 0.47 \\
15. I will work to make the world a better place.        & & 0.80 &&&&&& 0.68 \\
09. I will work for the betterment of society.  &  & 0.75 &&&&&& 0.59 \\

27. I will help people in need.     & & 0.74 &&&&&& 0.63 \\
21. I will help others improve their lives.     &  & 0.73 &&&&&& 0.63 \\
03. I will assist people who need it, asking nothing in return.     &  & 0.52 &&&&&& 0.34 \\
25. I will continue to grow and learn new things.& &&&&&&& 0.34 \\      
14. I will share my life with someone I love.   &  && 0.73 &&&&& 0.60 \\    
20. I will have committed, intimate relationships.  &  && 0.73 &&&&& 0.57 \\    
26. I will have deep, enduring relationships.       & &&  0.71 &&&&& 0.58 \\
02. I will feel that there are people who really love me, and whom I love.      &  && 0.54 &&&&& 0.37 \\
07. At the end of my life, I will look back on my life as meaningful and complete.      &  &&&&&&& 0.36 \\
08. I will have good friends that I can count on.& &&&&&&& 0.27 \\      
12. I will have a job that pays very well.&  &&& 0.88 &&&& 0.86 \\      
06. I will be financially successful.   &  &&& 0.80 &&&& 0.80 \\    
24. I will be rich.     &  0.44  &&& 0.51 &&&& 0.57 \\
10. My name will be known by many people.   &  0.40  &&&& 0.71 &&& 0.79 \\  
04. I will be recognized by lots of different people.   & &&&& 0.70 &&& 0.64 \\ 
16. I will be admired by many people.   &  0.43  &&&& 0.60 &&& 0.63 \\  
19. I will know and accept who I really am.     &  &&&&& 0.67 && 0.55 \\
13. I will gain increasing insight into why I do the things I do.   &  &&&&& 0.48 && 0.36 \\    
01. I will choose what I do, instead of being pushed along by life. &  &&&&&&& 0.19 \\  
22. I will be famous.       &  0.46  &&&&&& 0.72 & 0.82 \\
28. My name will appear frequently in the media.    &  0.42  &&&&&& 0.71 & 0.74 \\  
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
Varianzaufklärung in \% & 14.71 & 10.50 & 8.13 & 7.52 & 5.89 & 4.91 & 4.52 &{Gesamt}\\
\end{tabularx}

\end{table}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. I'd replace `\bottomrule` with `\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]`, though, and I'd remove the `\newline` instruction between `Varianzaufklärung` and `in \%`. Finally, `\multicolumn{1}{c}{Kommunalität}` may be replaced with just `{Kommunalität}`.

Comment: @Mico: Thanks for your feedback. You definitely spotted some thing I had missed. I have updated my answer to incorporate your suggestions.

Comment: Thank you very much @leandriis for your suggestions and also for the explanations as to what exactly you changed. I have copied your code, but my table does not look close to yours. It does not fit onto one page and also the vertical space between rows is way larger. I have posted a picture of how it looks right now in the original question. Do you maybe know why my table does not look the same as yours? 

Thanks :)

Comment: It seems like you changed the default linespacing somewhere in you document. Without seeing a full compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce the output you get, it is hard to tell what you can change to make the table fit onto the page.

Comment: @leandriis Okay thank you. I will change the code above with my minimal working example :)

Comment: @leandriis Ok, I got it. I have included in the preamble
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.6}. That was the issue. Thank you very much for your help :=)